# Magento 2 Admin form dropdown static options

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent, adminform

How can I add some static dropdown option in admin from by uiComponent.

I am using this but it's not working.

```
        <field name="gender">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">
                    <item value="0" xsi:type="string">Doesn't Matter</item>
                    <item value="1" xsi:type="string">Male</item>
                    <item value="2" xsi:type="string">Female</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Gender</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">job</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">gender</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your `options` item with

```
           <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Doesn't Matter</item>
                </item>
                <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Male</item>
                </item>
                <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Female</item>
                </item>
            </item>
```